# Utilizing wildcards and variables for getFiles

Tags: vb.net

I am kinda new to VB.net, so I am not sure if I try this the right way. I have the following piece of code.

```
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
    Dim TextLine As String
    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1


            Dim newString As String = TextLine.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "") & ".wav"
            Dim SongName As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(newString)
            Dim MyFile As String = Dir("C:\AllSongs\" & newString)
            Dim Searchquery As IEnumerable(Of String) = IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\AllSongs", "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(f) IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).IndexOf(SongName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            For Each Result In Searchquery

                ListBox1.Items.Add(Result)
            Next
```

I am trying to use the lines in the text file, and get the .wav in AllSongs dir that partially correspond in these files. Can it be done?
 Edit: Part of the code contains a media player. I want to be able to play songs from this player, by choosing files in the list.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ListBox1.SelectedItem
        Dim variables As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        Dim selectedItem As Object = ListBox1.SelectedItem
        variables("MyDynamicVariable") = selectedItem  ' Set the value of the "variable"
        selectedItem1 = selectedItem
        Dim value As String = variables("MyDynamicVariable")  ' Retrieve the value of the variable
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to find all the files which have "DEUTSCHLAND" in their name, or do you have a variable named `DEUTSCHLAND` which contains the text to be searched for?

Comment: The first one. However, the Value of SongName (DEUTSCHLAND in this situation)could change. I am sorry, I should have made it more clear. This event is embedded in a loop, where the variable SongName changes

Comment: I think you might want `Dim Searchquery As IEnumerable(Of String) = IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\mymusic", "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(f) IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).IndexOf(songname, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Give me a minute to edit my question.

Comment: I don't see how Dim SongName as string = DEUTSCHLAND even compiles without quotes around DEUTSCHLAND, since you said it's not a variable.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson I have edited my question.

Comment: @george123 Given `TextLine = objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine`, `If TextLine = "NaN" Then` can never be true because `TextLine` is, *at a minimum*, `VbNewLine`.

Comment: I have "NaN" strings in text file. This isn't the part that doesn't work. The search part is the one that bothers me.

Comment: @george123 `"Nan" & VbNewLine` does not equal `"Nan"`. I think that you need to remove the ` & vbNewLine` - it does nothing useful in this situation.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, it seems you are right. Leftovers from previous trials.

Answer (score 0):

Incidental to the question, but important, is that when you're working with files it's often necessary to clean up some resources (file handles, I guess) that the operating system uses even though you don't see it directly in the code as written. There is a way of doing that automatically with the `Using` statement, as shown in the following code.

To find out if a filename contains some text (string), you can extract the filename with no path or extension with [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.8) and check if it contains the desired string with the [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) function, which lets you ignore uppercase/lowercase by specifying how to do the check.

I notice from an update to the question that some improvements can be made, such as using a Class for the song entries so that the displayed list can have more information behind it, which means that the song name can be shown on its own but you can get the full path to the file when you click on it.

I made a new Windows Forms project and added just a ListBox to it, and used this code to show the full path (which you can use for your media player) to the song when its name is double-clicked:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Public Class SongEntry
        Property Name As String
        Property FullName As String
    End Class

    Sub PopulateSongList(musicDirectory As String, songsList As String)
        Dim songList As New List(Of SongEntry)

        Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(songsList)
            Do While Not sr.EndOfStream

                Dim thisSong = sr.ReadLine()

                If thisSong <> "NaN" Then
                    Dim fs = Directory.EnumerateFiles(musicDirectory, "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
                             Where(Function(f) Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).IndexOf(thisSong, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0).
                             Select(Function(g) New SongEntry With {.Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(g), .FullName = g})

                    songList.AddRange(fs)
                End If

            Loop

        End Using

        ListBox1.DataSource = songList
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "FullName"

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick
        Dim lb = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
        If lb.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim fullPathToSong = lb.SelectedValue.ToString()
            MsgBox(fullPathToSong)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim songsList = "C:\temp\AllSongs\songsList.txt"
        Dim musicDirectory = "C:\temp\AllSongs"
        PopulateSongList(musicDirectory, songsList)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Tried this one, I get: {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator(Of String)} when I check the searchquery variable, but nothing apears in my listbox

Comment: @george123 I added two Option settings, which would be the very first lines of the code, that make it unnecessary to declare variable types when they can be inferred by the compiler and a slight change to the LINQ. Does that make it work now?

Comment: By adding these commands, other parts of the code become unavailable, since string can't be converted to char.

Comment: @george123 Is `FILE_NAME` set to the *full* path of the file? Not just "wavlist.txt", but starting with a drive letter, like "C:\AllSongs\wavlist.txt". The code as shown works on my computer with some .wav files in "C:\temp\WAV" (instead of "C:\AllSongs", for the purposes of testing).

Comment: Yes. It's ""C:\Users\etc\etc\etc"

Comment: So if I find a way to work around string can't be converted to char. , this is gonna work?

Comment: @george123 Please edit the question to include a small example of the file with the strings to look for.

Comment: @george123 "string can't be converted to char" - where does that come in to it?

Comment: AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ListBox1.SelectedItem

Comment: @george123 `Option Strict On` is important because it makes variables be what you intend them to be instead of what the computer imagines they could be to make the code work as someone else thinks it should. If you correct the problems it shows, the code has much more chance of working the way you want it to.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your time and your tries.

Comment: It didn't work. Maybe it has to do that my txt file doesn't have paths in it?

Comment: @george123 Which part doesn't work? I notice that you added some code for ListBox1.DoubleClick - is that what isn't working?

Comment: @george123 I added some extra code, which I think will make it work as you want.